# why $& can't be used together in html (like $&nbsp;)

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

recently in Ionic, I used a statement given below.

```html
<ion-item>
      <p class=" header">Total price</p>
      <p class="sub-header">$&nbsp;{{price}}</p>
    </ion-item>
```

after using statements, All ionic commands stop working:-
ionic serve,
ionic cordova run android
[image: commands stop at transpile started]

Comment: Hmmm seems like you may need to add a "semicolon"?  Try "&nbsp;" instead

Comment: I have used .but forgot to put in question. my bad

Comment: It looks like an ionic issue rather than anything. It is valid HTML.